# How can I create this mysql "SELECT" query?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two mysql tables named 'categories' and 'products'.

These are data of that tables.

```
mysql> select * from categories;
+-------------+--------+----------------------+-------------+
| category_id | parent | name                 | description |
+-------------+--------+----------------------+-------------+
|           1 |   NULL | Products             | NULL        |
|           2 |      1 | Computers            | NULL        |
|           3 |      2 | Laptops              | NULL        |
|           4 |      2 | Desktop Computers    | NULL        |
|           5 |      2 | Tab PCs              | NULL        |
|           6 |      2 | CRT Monitors         | NULL        |
|           7 |      2 | LCD Monitors         | NULL        |
|           8 |      2 | LED Monitors         | NULL        |
|           9 |      1 | Mobile Phones        | NULL        |
|          10 |      9 | LG Phone             | NULL        |
|          11 |      9 | Anroid Phone         | NULL        |
|          12 |      9 | Windows Mobile       | NULL        |
|          13 |      9 | iPad                 | NULL        |
|          14 |      9 | Samsung Galaxy       | NULL        |
|          15 |      1 | Digital Cameras      | NULL        |
|          16 |      1 | Printers and Toners  | NULL        |
|          22 |      1 | Computer Accessaries | NULL        |
|          23 |     22 | USB Cables           | NULL        |
|          24 |     22 | Network Cables       | NULL        |
+-------------+--------+----------------------+-------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select product_id, category_id from products;
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | category_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |          24 |
|          2 |           6 |
|          3 |           6 |
|          4 |           6 |
+------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Now I need to create a select query to get products to each category. I have already have `category_id`.

This is how I tried it:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE category_id = 6 
ORDER BY added_date DESC
```

My question is when I creating this select query I need all the products if one category have its subcategories. That mean, if category_id is 2, then I need to get all the products including its sub categories.

Can anybody tell me how I create this select query?

Thank you.

Comment: Sub categories for category_id 2 are 22, 23 and 24?

Comment: no. 3,4,5,6,7,8 are sub categories for category_id 2. You can see categories' data in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE category_id = 2 OR 
      category_id IN (SELECT category_id
                      FROM categories
                      WHERE parent = 2)
ORDER BY added_date DESC
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is a duplicate answer .

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select a.*,b.* from categories a inner join products b on a.category_id = b.category_id where a.category_id='$Category_id' or a.parent_id='$category_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a sub-query to get `category_id` values whose `parent` is `2`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE category_id = 2 OR 
      category_id IN (SELECT category_id
                      FROM categories
                      WHERE parent = 2)
ORDER BY added_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers will work but only for one level deep of categories. If you need sub-sub-categories then I'd suggest using something called [MPTT](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/). This will require 2 new fields in your categories database table though (typically called `left` and `right`).